# Need sort of 'one-way AC relay' for connecting two L-OUT sources to feed a single L-IN destination

Tags: ac, relay

I need an AC analog of what in DC world would be `1 x relay and 2 x one-way diodes`.

To clarify what I am doing: I am going to have a heating pump (`Device 1`), a thermostat (`Device 2`) and a water pump (`Device 3`).

Both `Device 1` and `Device 2` are fed with `L IN` and may produce Line on the `L OUT`, in this case `Device 3` should work (means it should receive L IN on its connector).
The logic of when Line appears at `L OUT` connectors is out of this question scope.

I need to feed the `Device 3` with L using `OR` scheme (0-1-1-1).
I can not just connect those `L OUT(1)`+`L OUT(2)`+`L IN(3)` wires, because the source devices do not expect the Line on those `L OUT` when it's off and it will probably damage the source devices.

Please advice if I need some specific relay for that, if I may use any `AC-AC` relay for this purpose and/or maybe there are some other things I should take into account.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect the switch contacts of two AC-controlled relays in parallel:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnkOpi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That way the load ("device 3") turns on whenever one (or both) of the relays is on.

You don't need any kind of special relay for this.

Comment: Thank you. Question. If let's say 'L OUT DEV 1' is off and 'L OUT DEV2' is on, would the wire be shortened (i.e. L OUT DEV 1 will receive Line on its end)? Basically what I am asking is if I need sort of a DC one-way diode. Unfortunately I am not really good at AC, but I do not want to damage my heating pump with some unwanted Line on its L OUT terminal when it does not expect it.

Comment: The "other end" of the relay coil is connected to Neutral in this schematic. Current can only flow from the output, through the relay coil, to Neutral. There's no other path for it to take. There won't just suddenly be Line at the device output unless the device itself does it.